# How to display a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I want to look at a query used to create a table. The table was created already. I've seen this done in the past in the command console, but I cant find how to do this now. It was something like:

```css
show create; --OR 
select create; --none of these work
```

After running that it will display the query and some details about mysql.

Comment: It's pretty trivial to Google. https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+show+create

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename

Comment: @ceejayoz your search in google has the keywords. You already know what youre searching for. I dont recall either.

Comment: @Zapp I used the words **you** put in your post. You thought it might be `show create`. Typing `mysql show create` returned clear results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name` is the syntax in mysql. [MySql Refernce](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/show-create-table.html).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you're talking about [show create table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html)